# Interactive QML module with C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml

I am trying to create a text overlay with a transparent background to display text over a screen.

My application starts with the application example [conway's game of life](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-tableview-gameoflife-example.html). I removed the timer and set the cell grid to be transparent. This way my text on screen is shown in a grid format. The idea being at row 0, column 5, I can insert the letter 'H' for example. I register the model in qml so I can use it in an application rather than as a plugin.

I also changed the file "gosperglidergun.cells" to just contain the text "example Text".

I start my QT application in its own thread, as in it is not in the main thread of my application. The idea is for the thread running the QT application to handle editing text in the grid which overlays on the screen. The parent thread is in charge of passing in the text to be added to the screen or if text needs deleted.

The parent thread code is:

```
std::thread qtThread = std::thread([&]() { runQtThread(); });
while(1)
{
  // Handle inserting and removing text here
}
```

The following is what is written inside "runQtThread".

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

qmlRegisterType<GameOfLifeModel>("GameOfLifeModel", 1, 0, "GameOfLifeModel");

engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;
app.exec();
```

I can see the example text on screen. This is great. I feel like I have gotten somewhere and now nearer to my goal. The next step is to interactively edit the text that is seen overlaid onto the screen. My issue is, that I see no way to access the setData function in the GameOfLifeModel. This way I can change the data inside the container and emit the signal that data was changed. It seems this is really the only thing I need to be able to do and I can clear/add text to the screen through a c++ interface.

If this is not clear, let me know and I'll edit or add any extra information to help with the understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm really only trying to change the data that is written to screen and let QML take care of the rest. Unfortunately, the text to display will come externally from another device, which is why it is being handled outside the Qt thread.

Comment: Let's simplify the question: are you trying to read/write data that lives in the C++ part of the code from QML?

Comment: The data certainly lives in the C++ code and I would like QML to read and write. To be clear, the C++ code from the game of life model is completely separate from the main thread where I created another thread to run the Qt application. That code really seems to just be run from QML.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to pass in the text that I want displayed to screen via QML through a C++ interface. The solution was derived from the QT documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html).

I understand that there are many sources claiming that mixing C++ with QML can be confusing to determine where changes to information may be changed, either through QML or C++. I therefore have attempted to create a clear as possible c++ interface by creating specific roles. The C++ interface just supplies the text information and QML is in charge of the rest. All formatting, sizing, borders, and visual indicators are handled by QML.

For my specific use case the text data comes in from an external source. The incoming data could have multiple uses. The first couple bytes of the message determine what the incoming data is used for. Sometimes it is text to display. The entire project is not meant to be one big UI. QML is just being used to overlay text onto the screen on top of a video the user is seeing. The overlay does not have any buttons or interactive parts for the user.

Onward to the code. I basically had to create a QML object that could be referenced outside the thread starting up the GUI process. I did this by creating a component.

```
// Inside main.cpp
#define MAIN_QML_PATH "qml/main.qml"
#define REGISTERED_MODEL_NAME "GameOfLifeModel"

std::shared_ptr<Object> qmlObject;

...

// runQML is called in a new thread called in main.cpp
void runQML()
{
    int numArguments = 0;
    QGuiApplication app(numArguments, nullptr);

    qmlRegisterType<GameOfLifeMOdel>(REGISTERED_MODEL_NAME, 1, 0, REGISTERED_MODEL_NAME);

    std::string mainQML = MAIN_QML_PATH;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile(QString(mainQML.c_str())));
    qmlObject = std::shared_ptr<QObject>(component.create());

    QGuiApplication::exec();
}
```

I then created a function inside of the main.qml file

```
function setTextDataOnScreen(text: string, row: int, column: int) {
        gridTextRendererModel.setText(text, row, column);
    }
```

This QML function needs to be matched to a function in the registered GameOfLifeModel in c++. Therefore in the gameOfLife C++ code:

```
// gameOfLifeModel.h
Q_INVOKABLE void setText(const QString& text, int row, int column);

// gameOfLifeModle.cpp
void GameOfLifeModel::setText(const QString& text, int row, int column)
{
    // Edit m_currentState in this function and emit dataChanged(...);
}
```

Lastly, it is now needed to have a call to invoke the QML code directly:

```
// Inside the main thread that calls another thread to start up QT
void sendTextToScreen(const std::string& text, int row, int column)
{
    if (qmlObject == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    QString qText = QString::fromStdString(text);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qmlObject.get(), "setTextDataOnScreen", Q_ARG(QString, qText),
                              Q_ARG(int, row), Q_ARG(int, column));
}
```

There it is. I hope this helps someone else. I'll just reiterate, the developer needs to cautious when mixing a C++ interface and QML. Clearly defined roles should be created and kept within the scope of the code. Otherwise, it'll be impossible to debug problems later down the line.